# Run npm install only when needed and/or partially

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, npm, gulp

We call Gulp from our `csproj` file as we're using Visual Studio 2013 for this project:

```xml
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Exec Command="gulp" />
</Target>
```

However, since we're still crafting this fresh project, we often extend the `gulpfile.js` to include new packages. The dev will do e.g. `npm install gulp-util --save-dev` and write a new task, and all is well.

The developer then checks the `gulpfile.js` and `packages.json` in to our VCS. Currently:

- Teamcity has an extra build step `npm install`;
- Every developer has to run `npm install` manually;

Having to *remember* something that has to be done *manually* is not a great spot to be in. At one point we had this in our `csproj` file inside the `Task`...

```xml
 <Exec command="npm install" />
```

...just before the `gulp` exec, so developers could not "forget" to take this manual step. However, this can take one or even multiple seconds on each (re)build, which is annoying.

Is there any better way to solve this? How do you handle updates to `packages.json` in projects where large(ish) teams develop using Visual Studio?

Comment: How about calling `npm install` on `AfterRebuild` instead of `AfterBuild`?

Comment: I had considered that, but that makes for an obscure developer experience. E.g. a consequence is that after a fresh checkout of this project, a plain `Build` would *not* cause `npm install` and thus fail. But still a workaround worth considering if no real solution presents itself...

Answer (score 51):

An approach that works for me is to use [MSBuild incremental build support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-incrementally) in combination with a stamp file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- File with mtime of last successful npm install -->
  <NpmInstallStampFile>node_modules/.install-stamp</NpmInstallStampFile>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="NpmInstall"
  BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"
  Inputs="package.json"
  Outputs="$(NpmInstallStampFile)">
  <Exec Command="npm install" />
  <Touch Files="$(NpmInstallStampFile)" AlwaysCreate="true" />
</Target>
```

The `NpmInstall` `Target` only runs when `package.json` is newer than `node_modules/.install-stamp` and it touches that file after a successful `npm install`.  This way `npm install` is only run once after each change to `package.json`.

Comment: Instead of using your own stamp file, you can just use the node_modules folder itself as the output. npm seems to touch it every time it runs an install.

Comment: @ILMTitan Unless npm explicitly changes the mtime of `node_modules`, it would only change when a directory is added/removed.  So if a `package.json` change did not result in added/removed directories in `node_modules`, I think `npm install` would be run on every build until `node_modules` changed.

Comment: I just double checked. On my windows system, running `npm install` does update the last write time of the `node_modules` folder, even when it makes no changes.

Comment: It didn't update node_modules for me. But using a timestamp file in an ignored directory is easy enough. Thanks for the idea, works great.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there's no way to install only the new packages in npm, but you could try to reduce the time spent during this step with tools like [npm-fast-install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-fast-install) or [npm_lazy](http://mixu.net/npm_lazy/).

Comment: Obviously you deserve the bounty for "*question hasn't received enough attention*", as you were the only one to give it some visible attention :-). Not a satisfying answer though (i.e. it comes down to "*can't be done / only workarounds available*" AFAICT). In any case: thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 1):

[npm-install-missing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-install-missing) combines `npm outdated` and `npm install` to install all missing dependencies within the dependency tree.

You can add it to your project like this:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Exec command="npm-install-missing" />
  <Exec Command="gulp" />
</Target>
```